# Colors are off in SDL program

Tags: c, opengl, sdl

I am currently working on a very simple game using a pure C approach with SDL (and its official extra libraries such as SDL_image) and OpenGL. Right now though I've hit a bit of a stumbling block and I have no idea why it is doing this: the colors are all off when drawn. I am running the program on a Mac currently, but if I remember correctly when I run it in Windows the colors are closer to being correct, but there are still some odd things happening (such as a pure white polygon drawing as yellow).

Currently on my Mac all images that are loaded as png files have their color drawn a bit off, and a pure white polygon is drawn as dark green. There are also a few images that are drawn pure white. If I remember correctly on Windows, the images are drawn correctly but the white polygon is yellow, as mentioned earlier. Now I'll post the pertinent code for initialization and loading and such.

```
int main( int argc, char *argv[] ) {
//initializing various OpenGL attributes with SDL utilities
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute( SDL_GL_DOUBLEBUFFER, 1 );
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute( SDL_GL_DEPTH_SIZE, 16 ); //needs for 3D
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute( SDL_GL_RED_SIZE, 8 ); //only needed for systems other than mac osx
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute( SDL_GL_GREEN_SIZE, 8 );
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute( SDL_GL_BLUE_SIZE, 8 );
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute( SDL_GL_ALPHA_SIZE, 8 );

    /* Set 640x480 video mode */
    screen=SDL_SetVideoMode(screen_width,screen_height, 8, videoflags );
        if (screen == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Couldn't set %dx%dx%d video mode: %s\n",
                        screen_width, screen_height,
                        video_info->vfmt->BitsPerPixel, SDL_GetError());
        exit(2);
    }

    glShadeModel( GL_SMOOTH );

    glClearColor( 0.3f, 0.3f, 0.3f, 0 );

    glViewport( 0, 0, (GLsizei)screen->w, (GLsizei)screen->h );

    glMatrixMode( GL_PROJECTION );
    glLoadIdentity();

    gluOrtho2D( 0.0f, screen->w, 0.0f, screen->h );

    /*glEnable( GL_BLEND );
    glBlendFunc( GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA );*/
    glEnable( GL_ALPHA_TEST );
    glAlphaFunc( GL_GREATER, 0.1f );

// Some basic initialization stuff goes here
// Assume infinite while loop goes here, except when esc is pressed

        glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT );
        glMatrixMode( GL_MODELVIEW );
        glLoadIdentity();

        glEnable( GL_TEXTURE_2D );
        draw_gui();

        // Things get drawn here

        glDisable( GL_TEXTURE_2D );

        SDL_GL_SwapBuffers();
        SDL_Delay( 10 );

// End of while loop, clean up, etc.
}
```

Now I'll show the code that actually loads an image into memory:

```
Sprite *gen_sprite( char *file ) {
    SDL_Surface *buffer = IMG_Load( file );
    if( buffer == NULL ) {
        fprintf( stderr, "Could not load image '%s'\n for reason: %s\n",
                file, IMG_GetError() );
        exit( 3 );
    } 
    return gen_sprite_from( buffer );
}

Sprite *gen_sprite_from( SDL_Surface *buffer ) {
    Sprite *sprite;
    GLuint texture;

    if( buffer == NULL ) {
        fprintf( stderr, "NULL surface passed to gen_sprite_from." );
        exit( 3 );
    }    
    texture = gen_Gl_texture_from( buffer );
    if( ( sprite = malloc( sizeof( Sprite ) ) ) == NULL ) {
        fprintf( stderr, "Malloc failed to allocate space for a Sprite.\n" );
        exit( 1 );
    }
    if( ( sprite->tex = malloc( sizeof( GLuint ) ) ) == NULL ) {
        fprintf( stderr, "Malloc failed to allocate space for a GLuint.\n" );
        exit( 1 );
    }
    sprite->tex[ 0 ] = texture;
    sprite->original = buffer;
    sprite->is_animation = 0;
    sprite->cur_frame = 0;
    sprite->cur_time = 0;
    sprite->num_frames = 1;
    sprite->frame_time = NULL;

    return sprite;
}

Uint32 gen_Gl_texture_from( SDL_Surface *buffer ) {
    GLuint texture;
    SDL_Surface *temp;

    glPixelStorei( GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 4 );
    glGenTextures( 1, &texture );
    temp = SDL_CreateRGBSurface( SDL_SWSURFACE, buffer->w, buffer->h, 32,

        0x000000FF, 0x0000FF00, 0x00FF0000, 0xFF000000 );
    SDL_SetAlpha( buffer, 0, SDL_ALPHA_OPAQUE );
    SDL_BlitSurface( buffer, NULL, temp, NULL );
    glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture );
    //glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST );
    //glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST );
    glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR );
    glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR );
    glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_GENERATE_MIPMAP, GL_TRUE );
    gluBuild2DMipmaps( GL_TEXTURE_2D, 4,
                      temp->w, temp->h,
                      GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,
                      temp->pixels );
    SDL_FreeSurface( temp );

    // This just creates white blocks instead of actually loading textures
    //glPixelStorei( GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, buffer->format->BytesPerPixel );
    //glGenTextures( 1, &texture );
    //glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture );
    //glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR );
    //glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR );
    //glTexImage2D( GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, mask_order, buffer->w, buffer->h, 0,
    //  mask_order, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, buffer->pixels );

    return texture;
}
```

At this point, I believe all the code that is pertinent for why colors would be skewed has been posted. Drawing code is very simple and just involves something such as a translation or rotation, binding a texture, and then a simple begin/end block with texcoords and vertices. If anyone can tell me why colors are off, and let me know a good way to make sure that colors are always correct in a cross-platform way (I plan to build on all platforms, which is part of the reason I'm using SDL) I would really appreciate it.

Comment: `screen=SDL_SetVideoMode(screen_width,screen_height, 8, videoflags );` Would set up 8 bits for colour... you seem to want 32, don't you?

Comment: Changing it to 32 (or 0 to let SDL use the current screen's attributes) doesn't seem to do anything different. The drawn polygon is still dark green when it is supposed to be white.

Comment: Instead of `temp = SDL_CreateRGBSurface( SDL_SWSURFACE, buffer->w, buffer->h, 32, 0x000000FF, 0x0000FF00, 0x00FF0000, 0xFF000000 );` try `temp = SDL_CreateRGBSurface( SDL_SWSURFACE, buffer->w, buffer->h, buffer->format->BitsPerPixel, buffer->format->Rmask, buffer->format->Gmask, buffer->format->Bmask, buffer->format->Amask);`. It might mess up your alpha rendering initially if you haven't set buffer as a surface with alpha enabled.

Comment: I'm very specifically using the set values there so that the end surface that I am creating is in GL_RGBA format, which I hear is faster for OpenGL to actually render. It also makes sure that all surfaces are standardized. I believe buffer is created with alpha rendering and that the call to SDL_SetAlpha make sure the alpha channel is properly transferred to the new surface.

Comment: ```glClearColor( 0.3f, 0.3f, 0.3f, 0 );``` is asking for a grey of 0.3f, fair enough, but that 0 at the end is asking for one that is completely transparent. You probably want one that is opaque... ```glClearColor( 0.3f, 0.3f, 0.3f, 1.0f );```

Answer (score 4):

Your channels are getting mixed up.

The problem is evident in the following lines:

```
temp = SDL_CreateRGBSurface( SDL_SWSURFACE, buffer->w, buffer->h, 32,
    0x000000FF, 0x0000FF00, 0x00FF0000, 0xFF000000 );
```

and:

```
gluBuild2DMipmaps( GL_TEXTURE_2D, 4,
                  temp->w, temp->h,
                  GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,
                  temp->pixels );
```

You are specifying a 32-bit texture in SDL made of 32-bit units, and then you are specifying an OpenGL texture as 4 8-bit components.  This may give you correct or incorrect results depending on your architecture's endian.  The solution is to specify OpenGL textures not as `GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE` but as `GL_UNSIGNED_INT` as follows:

```
gluBuild2DMipmaps( GL_TEXTURE_2D, 4,
                  temp->w, temp->h,
                  GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_INT_8_8_8_8,
                  temp->pixels );
```

Or maybe `GL_UNSIGNED_INT_8_8_8_8_REV` is correct, I'm too lazy to figure out which one matches your SDL texture specification.  Or you can change the SDL texture specification.  A similar format (actually `GL_BGRA` / `GL_UNSIGNED_INT_8_8_8_8_REV`, I *think*, I might be wrong) matches a commonly supported internal format exactly and will be *slightly* faster to upload to your graphics card but you won't notice unless you upload a lot of textures.

As a stylistic note, it is generally preferred to specify the internal format more exactly, like this:

```
gluBuild2DMipmaps(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_RGBA8, ....
```

Comment: GL_RGBA/GL_UNSIGNED_INT_8_8_8_8_REV I believe seems to mostly be fixing things. However, the white polygon I am attempting to draw is still dark green, and there are still a couple textures that are ending up as white when they were fine on Windows. The white textures might be a separate problem now that I think about it, and I'll see if I can find a cause for that.